# Use different analyzer depending on node property in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am creating a single database to store nodes with content in several languages.

I have a model like:

```
(Book {title, summary, text})<-[WRITES {date}]-(Author {name, lang})
```

I would like to be able to perform full text search on Book's titles and text in several language.

I have tried to simply create several index with different analyzer in a very stupid way:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.createNodeIndex("searchEN",["Book"],["title", "summary", "text"], {analyzer: "english")
CALL db.index.fulltext.createNodeIndex("searchFR",["Book"],["title", "summary", "text"], {analyzer: "french")
```

But when I try to create the index for french I get this error:

```
neobolt.exceptions.ClientError: There already exists an index NODE:label[0](property[1], property[9], property[11]).
```

A solution I would like would to limit a search in English to books that are written by an English speaking author without having to create a new node type like `EnglishBook`. I want to avoid it because other node types of the schema can share connections with books of different language.

For instance I still want to be able to do:

```
MATCH (p: Publisher)-[r: PUBLISHES]->(b: Book)
RETURN p, r, b
```

Comment: Try using different property names for different languages. E.g., "title_fr" for French titles.

Comment: That would also work but would break queries to fetch all titles from all languages seaminglessly. The best solution would be the possibility to add a `WHERE` clause when creating the index.